# Add background Image to body with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to add

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: url('example_img.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

to page source with selenium python.

what should I do? I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.